# How many ways are there to arrange a sequence of 5 distinct numbers such that no 3 consecutive numbers are strictly increasing?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

For example, let's say we have a set of 5 numbers: $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$

The order $1, 3, 2, 5, 4$ would work but $1, 3, 2, 4, 5$ wouldn't. I have no idea how to approach this, any help?

My own progress:
I tried to arrange them in decreasing order and then swap a number with a number that comes after it. I feel like that doesn't take into account every possible arrangement even if the same procedure is done for every number, though.

Comment: Can you give some context for the problem? If you just want to calculate it then given the small size of the sample space I'd probably just write a script and go the brute force route, but that might not be what you're looking for

Comment: I'm trying to solve this via combinations and permutations rather than through coding it.

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion is the best approach. It gets harder for more than $5.$

Comment: I have no idea how to apply inclusion exclusion principle to this though.

Comment: This will probably be closed if you don’t show any effort on your part, however.

Comment: I did try to make a procedural approach, trying to select spots for the members before swapping them around to make sure that no 3 are in increasing order. You can arrange them in decreasing order and then you would be able to swap any 1 number with a number that comes after it. I feel like that doesn't take into account every possible arrangement, though.

Comment: A) How many cases are there where the first 3 digits are strictly increasing? Middle 3? Last 3? B) First 4 or last 4?  C) All 5? D) Hence, what does PIE tell us about the cases where some set of 3 digits are strictly increasing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are careful, you can solve this with complementary counting, That is, you only need the "exclusion" part of the principle of inclusion exclusion.

The "bad" permutations $[a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5]$ fall into one of three categories:

1. Permutations where $a_3<a_4<a_5$.
2. Permutations where $a_2<a_3<a_4$, but $a_4>a_5$.
3. Permutations where $a_1<a_2<a_3$, but $a_3>a_4$.

The reason for the "but" clauses is to ensure these three bad categories are disjoint, to prevent double-counting. In effect, we are grouping together bad permutations according to the rightmost occurrence of its three increasing entries.

Anyways, there are $5!/3!=20$ permutations in the first category (each of the $3!$ relative orderings of $a_3,a_4$ and $a_5$ are equally likely) and $5!/(4\cdot 2)=15$ permutations in each of the second and third categories. To explain the count for category $2$, note that $a_2<a_3<a_4>a_5$ occurs if and only if $a_4$ is the largest of $\{a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5\}$, and if $a_2<a_3$. These are independent events with probabilities $1/4$ and $1/2$, respectively.

Therefore, the number of good permutations is $120-20-15-15=70$.

<strike>The same method works seamlessly for permutations of length $6$. However, once we get to length $7$, this method will still have some double-counting to deal with.</strike>  Never mind, there is double counting already for length $6$, since it is possible to have $a_1<a_2<a_3>a_4<a_5<a_6$, i.e, you can have two increasing sequences of length $3$ which are not part of a larger increasing subsequence.

Comment: My brute force Python program confirms my answer. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BaoNgEITP@Z9iblEqJcb0Upo38NibSPkxa12I@8u6JoSQZ7digsXDMvDNMMx2N2uCZONYa2jBRmohnHtw2wU1dKTtYN44SO@cDO3PxZ/5hCN2rg6KHCyrUFSkyT7JkkPyUcafbsM1JFiUF7sSX8iL9Cn7MoaX08tb4CzZylvgLIe5dPM/5O2I1LlOWSyqt98NKcFPd18ij9U@XNmaqRrWKBGqCVE1GF9o@qRS8j3LL0hMmfr3bTyOfw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Which proves I did not do it right. Missed some digits when I first listed the permutations.

Comment: When i apply this question for $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ ,  I always find $720 - 480+103-14+1 =330$ but answer is given $349$ in your  computer program in the link (i set it up for this question)

Comment: You aren't using my method, you're using Calvin's. Here's how mine works. For $6$, there are four bad categories. $\tag*{}$
$C_1$: $a_4<a_5<a_6$. $\tag*{}$ 
$C_2$: $a_3<a_4<a_5>a_6$. $\tag*{}$ 
$C_3$ $a_2<a_3<a_4>a_5$. $\tag*{}$ 
$C_4$: $a_1<a_2<a_3>a_4$. $\tag*{}$ 
It is easy to see $|C_1|=6!/3!=120$, and as before, $|C_2|=|C_3|=|C_4|=6!/(4\cdot 2)=90$. However, there is some double subtracting in $6!-120-90-90-90$, since $C_1$ and $C_4$ overlap. It turns out $|C_1\cap C_4|=6!/(3!\cdot 3!)-1=19$, so the final count is $720-120-90-90-90+19=349$. Done! @Bulbasaur

Comment: @MikeEarnest thanks Mike ,  i think that Calvins method makes sense for $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ ,as well. However , i cannot see where i make mistake in his method

Answer (score 4):

As per my comment, just apply PIE.

Let $ A $ be the configurations where the first 3 are increasing.
Let $ B $ be the configurations where the middle 3 are increasing.
Let $ C $ be the configurations where the last 3 are increasing.

We are interested in the set of all configurations excluding $ A \cup B \cup C$.
PIE states that

$$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B | - |B \cap C | - |C \cap A| + |A \cap B \cap C |,$$
so we just need to hunt down these values.

Applying basic permutations counting, we can show that

> $|A| =  20, |B| = 20, |C| = 20$,
>  $|A \cap B| = 5, |B \cap C | = 5, |A \cap C | = 1 $,
>  $|A \cap B \cap C | = 1 $

Hence, by PIE,

> $|A \cup B \cup C| = 20 + 20 + 20 - 5 - 5 - 1 + 1 = 50$.

Thus, the number of allow configurations is $ 120 - 50 = 70$.

---

Notes

- It is not that much harder for 6 numbers, as long as you carefully list out the $ \cap A$, and consider how they overlap. Try it for yourself.
- However, it quickly becomes tedious (unless you have a great way or categorizing the possible intersections).
- I intentionally avoided calling them $ A_i$, because $A_i \cap A_j$ greatly depends on the $i,j$ values.

Comment: Did you use bjection property to calculate $|A|,|B|,|C|$ such that$C(5,3) \times 2!$ or for $|A \cap B| = C(5,4)$ .?

Comment: @Bulbasaur That's one way to think about it. Alternatively, for $|A|$, there are  $ C(5,3)$ ways to pick the first 3 numbers, and a unique way to arrange them in increasing order, and then 2 ways to arrange the last 2 numbers.

Comment: It is what i wrote , why did you say "alternatively" ? It is bijection

Comment: Moreover if it were $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ , then the answer would be $$6! - [C(6,3) \times 3! + C(6,3) \times 3! + C(6,3) \times 3! +C(6,3) \times 3!  - C (6,4) \times 2! - C (6,4) \times 2! - C (6,4) \times 2! +C(6,5) + C(6,5)-C(6,6)]=720-(4 \times 120) + (3 \times 30)-(2 \times 6)+1=319$$ . Am I true ?

Comment: Is there any mistake in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ ?

Comment: @Bulbasaur It doesn't seem right, at least to the naive look. Can you list out what you're doing, perhaps as another solution. Note that the number of intersections of 2 sets should be 6, whereas it appears to me that you only have 3 (all of the form where 4 numbers are in strictly increasing order. In particular, $ |A \cap D| = 1$. Granted, this could have been cancelled out with (say) $|A\cap B \cap D|$.

Comment: I always find $720 - 480+103-14+1 =330$ but answer is given $349$ in computer program

Comment: @Bulbasaur Your mistake is in the $+103$. You correctly found $|A\cap B|=|B\cap C|=|C\cap D|=\binom64\cdot 2!=30$, and $|A\cap C|=|B\cap D|=\binom65\cdot 1!=6$, but you mistakenly have $|A\cap D|\stackrel{?}=1$, when it should be $|A\cap D|=\binom63=20$. Permutations  in $A\cap D$ have $a_1<a_2<a_3$ and $a_4<a_5<a_6$, so you choose $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ in $\binom63$ ways, and then the placement of everything is forced. You mistakenly thought that $A\cap D$ meant all six items were in increasing order, but really they are just two blocks of three increasing entries.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Agree with you that $ | A \cap D | = 20$, unlike my previous comment.

Comment: @MikeEarnest thank you very much Mike!